# Network speed capped in some applications

Tags: networking, internet

I have been problems with some apps on windows being download capped. I have run a Speedtest on https://ww.speedtest.net and also in the Windows Store App on the exact same server and back to back.
The result in the browser were:

12 ping, 388 mbps down, 52 mbps up

But in the App I was getting:
10 ping, 96mbps down, 52 mbps up

They were run under the exact same conditions seconds apart. This is a problem because it is also limiting my VR Streaming Application which need as much bandwidth as possible and it is also effected by the cap.

[Picture of the speedtests side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhMkv.png)